# Open PDF's from mail in my app

Tags: ios, swift, plist

Im coding this app in swift. The purpose of my app is just to open pdf files, but get them mainly from other sources, like mail. Meaning, you get an email with pdf attachment, tap the share button, app appears in the "Open in" menu alongside with Dropbox , Evernote, etc. Tap the app, pdf opens in the app.

For now i can open pdf in a WebView from a url. I tried to adding support for pdf's in *info.plist*:

```
<key>CFBundleDocumentTypes</key>
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
    <string>public.pdf</string>
    <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
    <string>Viewer</string>
    <key>LSHandlerRank</key>
    <string>Owner</string>
    <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
    <string>com.adobe.pdf</string>
</dict>
```

**Problem is:**

1. My app doesn't appear in the list of apps when i tap the share button. How to fix this?
2. How can I specifically pass in the pdf from the mail app to the WebView in my app?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: here are some help full links http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/importing-exporting-documents-ios?dm_switcher=true   and http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/importing-exporting-documents-ios?dm_switcher=tru

Comment: Sounds like you want to create an App Extension (share or Action).  Heres a link to the App Extension Programming Guide -https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014214-CH20-SW1